# PHP loop is overwriting array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have loop inception going on and I could use some help please.

I have to loop through some curl calls to an API, and get the records to then push to another API. Each call from this endpoint returns only 30 records, so I also need to loop through if there are more than 30.

I am trying to dump out an array at the end of all loops to see what I thought would be all the data, but it is only outputting 1 record.

Am I missing something dumb here?

```
$project_ids = array(
    '111111',
    '222222',
    );

$array = array();

foreach ($project_ids as $proj_id) {

    $go_again = true;
    $page = 1;
    $per_page = 30;

    while ( $go_again ) {

        $curl = curl_init($baseurl . $key_url);

        $keyPOSTdata = array(
            "date_format" => "d-m-Y",
            "page" => $page,
            "projects_id" => $proj_id,
        );

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($keyPOSTdata));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        $result = json_decode($response);
        $total =  $result->body->total_count;
        $new_total = $total - ($per_page * $page);

        if( $total - ($per_page * $page ) > 0 ) {
            ++$page;
        }
        else {
            $page = 1;
            $go_again = false;
        }

        curl_close($curl);

        foreach ($result->body as $item) {
            $array['attribute1'] = $item->attribute1;
            $array['attribute2'] = $item->attribute2;
            $array['attribute3'] = $item->attribute3;
        }

    }

}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
exit();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are, indeed, rewriting the array on each loop. Notice you don't initialize a new row for each record, you're only writing on the "attributeX" field over and over. This should work:

```
foreach ($result->body as $item) {
    $record = [];
    $record['attribute1'] = $item->attribute1;
    $record['attribute2'] = $item->attribute2;
    $record['attribute3'] = $item->attribute3;
    $array[] = $record;
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, makes sense now why rewriting was happening ha. However, I get no change in output when changing to this method.. still just one item being dumped...

Comment: I think you’re not iterating over every element of the response, only over the body of one element. You’ll probably need two `foreach` inside the while loop. Can you please edit in your question a sample response?

Comment: So I got it working, by moving the new $record temp array, and the $array[] assignment to inside the foreach loop...

Comment: Right. Sorry, was a bit hard doing this without looking at the actual data. Glad you got it working! I edited the answer to reflect what worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your items per project ID, then you probably want:

```
foreach ($result->body as $i => $item) {
    $record[$proj_id][$i]['attribute1'] = $item->attribute1;
    $record[$proj_id][$i]['attribute2'] = $item->attribute2;
    $record[$proj_id][$i]['attribute3'] = $item->attribute3;
}
```

Comment: Not sure this would work as the end array is the format I need to push to other API so cannot be multidimensional

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting here!

```
$array['attribute1'] = $item->attribute1;
$array['attribute2'] = $item->attribute2;
$array['attribute3'] = $item->attribute3;
```

Every loop will overwrite the values of these values.

You can resolve this in two ways,

```
foreach ($result->body as $key => $item) {
    $record[$key]['attribute1'] = $item->attribute1;
    $record[$key]['attribute2'] = $item->attribute2;
    $record[$key]['attribute3'] = $item->attribute3;
}
```

OR

```
foreach ($result->body as $key => $item) {
    $record['attribute1'][] = $item->attribute1;
    $record['attribute2'][] = $item->attribute2;
    $record['attribute3'][] = $item->attribute3;
}
```

It depends on your requirement, how you want array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$orderItemsHtml[] = array();

foreach ($order->products as $product) {
   $thisItem= [];
   $tempSKU                      = $product->product_sku;
   $tempQty                      = $product->pivot->quantity;

   $thisItem['name']             = $product->product_name;
   $thisItem['sku']              = $tempSKU;
   $thisItem['units']            = $tempQty;
   $thisItem['selling_price']    = $product->sale_price;
   
   $orderItemsHtml[]             = $thisItem;
}
```

Try this, should work.